# Using "CGI (every host may be set to a different PHP version)" causes gettext/_() to crash apache

Tags: php, mamp, gettext, mamp-pro, php-gettext

I'm using MAMO PRO (Trail) version 6.3 (30448). Currently I have to hosts set up, although this issue happens for no matter the number of hosts.

When I'm using the setting "Languages -> PHP -> Mode: CGI (every host may be set to a different PHP version)" it causes the website to crash. There's no errors in MySQL or PHP-logs.

However, I get this error in apache's logs:

```
FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.3.24.fcgi"
```

This happens no matter the PHP version. After ***alot*** (!!) of googling and finally stepping through the execution using xdebug I found out that this happens when using gettext/_() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php), which commonly is used in WordPress for translations.

The gettext extension is loaded according to phpinfo() and get_loaded_extensions().

Example. index.php file with this content:

```
echo gettext('Hello');
die;
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix this? It's driving me insanse. :-)

Comment: Same problem here, if anyone has a solution :D